# How to customize exo player in jetpack compose like adding custom playback controls, custom quality options, custom icons etc

Tags: android, user-interface, android-jetpack-compose, exoplayer, video-player

I want to create a video playing app in jetpack compose with plays online videos. The same video has different quality options on web but I cant find a way to implement it in android using jetpack compose. Also I want to customize how the player looks and change its default playback speed, add quality options, full screen mode etc.

I tried reading docs but couldnt find anything related to compose, please help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.